# Make row as one column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I know that "recommended" snippet for rows /columns in bootstrap is:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6"></div>
   <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

Everyting is fine - padding & margin are preserved in each column set.

But in my code there is a lot of stuff like:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12"></div>
</div>
```

Is this possible to merge it as one div?  I think I could write sth like this:

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
</div>
```

([JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15538/embedded/result/))

Unfortunatley it doesn's work (as you can see, 3rd row is shorter). What can I do to avoid additional div with `col-md-12`?

Comment: what you want actually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the difference is because `.row` defines a negative  `margin-left` and `margin-right` of `-15px` and `.col-*-*` defines a `width` of `100%`

**Bootstrap's css**

```
.row{
    margin-left:-15px;
    margin-right:-15px;
}

.col-[rest of class name]{
    width:100%;
}
```

The width of `100%` is causing the negative `margin` to be ignored.
If you override the negative margin, your div's will have the same width.

**Override bootstrap css**

```
.row{
  margin-left:0px;
  margin-right:0px;
}
```

While I would recommend sticking to bootstrap's intended usage, this will remedy your `width` problem.

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15539/